# Custom function works in "Zoom to Features" but not "Select Features"

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-custom-function

I'm trying to update the [Using Custom Functions tutorial](https://astuntechnology.github.io/qgis-tutorials/html/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html) to QGis 3 and Python 3 and I've run into an interesting issue. With the following code I can create an expression `GetUtmZone()='33N'` and it works in the Output preview, it works to zoom to the features but if I try to select features it says no features are found!

---

**Update**

There seems to be no issue with the function code as it works fine as a label and a map tip.

---

```
import math
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=True)
def GetUtmZone(feature, parent):
    centroid = feature.geometry()
    longitude = centroid.asPoint().x()
    latitude = centroid.asPoint().y()
    zone_number = math.floor(((longitude + 180) / 6) % 60) + 1

    if latitude >= 0:
        zone_letter = 'N'
    else:
        zone_letter = 'S'

    return '%d%s' % (int(zone_number), zone_letter)
```

[image]

The zoom to's are clearly working but each select returns the warning: No matching features found.

### versions etc:

> QGIS version
>   3.4.4-Madeira
>
> QGIS code revision
>   f6ddc62
>
> Compiled against Qt
>   5.9.5
>
> Running against Qt
>   5.9.5
>
> Compiled against GDAL/OGR
>   2.2.3
>
> Running against GDAL/OGR
>   2.2.3
>
> Compiled against GEOS
>   3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2
>
> Running against GEOS
>   3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6
>
> PostgreSQL Client Version
>   10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
>
> SpatiaLite Version
>   4.3.0a
>
> QWT Version
>   6.1.3
>
> QScintilla2 Version
>   2.10.2
>   PROJ.4 Version
>   493
>
> Linux astun-desktop 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Works fine for me, 3.4.0-Madeira. I'm testing on some Cumbria regions and `GetUtmZone() = '31N'` and click "select features" in "Select by expression" turns them all yellow. Zoom to Features also works...

Comment: And it doesn't work (same behaviour as yours) for a larger set of points across several zones (previous data was polygons all in 31N) - except I don't even get a warning... Just nothing selected.

Comment: Selection does seem to work if all the features in the layer are selected by the expression - otherwise none are. Have just tested that with a subset of the large set of points that are all in one zone.

Comment: Except I've just made a counter-example to that, with a dataset that has one point in another zone and 12 in another. Function will zoom to and select the data. So in conclusion... agggh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a combination of two things:

1. You have a typo, `usesGeometry` should be `usesgeometry`:

   @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
2. A bug in QGIS, fixed here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/9218

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't usesgeometry default to true anyway, so the typo shouldn't matter? I just going by the help in the editor window

Comment: Right -- those docs are wrong, it defaults to false. I'll fix.